# How do I see how many advancements I have on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

I have advancements and wonder how to see how many I have. I really want to see them. Is there a way to see them?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancement#Interface):

> The button to access the Advancements screen is found on the pause menu screen. The player can also open this screen by pressing <kbd>L</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly count manually, but the only way I can think of to count it automatically would require doing the command:

```
/advancements revoke @s everything
```

which should output a number like "removed 42 advancements", except I assume you don't want to remove said achievements, in which case the answer is no. There is no way to see the total amount that I know of.